# Limit Buffer Reader to prevent DoS Attack

Tags: java, security

I need help with the below code. I need to review it and fix the security issues within the code. The issue that I see is the `BufferReader` should read in chunks. This would possibly prevent a DOS Attack.The way the code is written now it will read a infinite length. I'm not sure the best way to limit the `BufferReader`.Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class example {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Read the filename from the command line argument
    String filename = args[0];
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;

    String fileLine;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        System.out.println("Email Addresses:");
        // Read one Line using BufferedReader
        while ((fileLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(fileLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("File IO exception" + io.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Need another catch for closing 
        // the streams          
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("Issue closing the Files" + io.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: *This would possibly prevent a DOS Attack.* No. It won't.

Comment: Please elaborate OP

Comment: Would the above code be acceptable to a DOS attack because the Buffer Reader  will read a infinite length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement behind the warning about `BufferedReader.readLine` is to impose a reasonable bound on the maximum amount of memory that an adversary can cause to be allocated at a time. In this case the important usage is the size of the `String` characters and roughly the same in the buffer used to create it. If the adversary can do this multiple times at once, then that will also need to be limited. Typically, if the resource can be stopped but not closed (for instance, over a network file system) then the buffer can be kept in memory indefinitely.

The easy, general solution is to implement an `InputStream` that limits the total number of bytes that can be read through it. That could also be implemented at the `Reader` level limiting the number of characters. The dirty way around is to ignore the `BufferedReader` and do the reading of `char` arrays and combining into a `StringBuilder` yourself.

Presumably various third party library include code that covers those approaches.

(Also: Do use try-with-resource. `FileReader` picks up whatever character coding has been left as the default, which is probably wrong. Adding `throws IOException` to `main` makes the simpler.)